# How do I format date in jQuery datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use jQuery [`datetimepicker`](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) which was extended from jQuery [`datepicker`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) to pick not only date but time too.

I want to set date/time format this way: `dd-mm-yyyy @ hh:mm`

```
$('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd:mm:yyyy',
  separator: ' @ ',
  minDate: new Date()
});
```

But this does not work. I get date/time in following format:

```
Thu Jan 27 2011 02:05:17 GMT+0100
```

Is there any javascript function to format this date/time? If not how do I do that using the plugin? Check out my code: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BqFTs/)

Comment: Why do you use a div (and not an input element)? Plus: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDateFormat.html may be useful.

Comment: I do not want an input...it does not work....and I use datetimepicker not just datepicker

Comment: Do you want the "alerted" value to be displayed as "dd-mm-yyyy @ hh:mm"?

Comment: it is alerted just for testing, later I want to store it in db

Answer (score 51, accepted):

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/BqFTs/3/).

```
$('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
   // dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
   format:'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
    minDate: getFormattedDate(new Date())
});

function getFormattedDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
    return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
```

You need to pass datepicker() the date formatted correctly.

Comment: This answer is outdated :o(

Answer (score 7):

Newer versions of datetimepicker (I'm using is use 2.3.7) use `format:"Y/m/d"` not `dateFormat...`

so

```
jQuery('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd-m-y',
    value: new Date()
});
```

See http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Comment: Is it possible to add time here? And to have year in format YYYY?

Comment: Spent some time debugging weird behavior in my app, until I found that the format was not the standard one. What kind of date formatting is this? Is there a reference for it somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

This works for me. Since it "extends" datepicker we can still use dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'.

```
$(function() {
    $('.jqueryui-marker-datepicker').datetimepicker({
        showSecond: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
      stepHour: 2,
      stepMinute: 10,
      stepSecond: 10

     });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

For example, I get date/time in format Spanish.

```
$('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    format:'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use :

```
$('#timePicker').datetimepicker({
        format:'d.m.Y H:i',
        minDate: ge_today_date(new Date())
});

 function ge_today_date(date) {
     var day = date.getDate();
     var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
     var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
     return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datePicker").datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
        defaultDate: new Date(),
    });
}
```

here are the CDN links

```
<!-- datetime picker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `format` option, as described in [the documentation](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

```
$("#timePicker").datetimepicker({
  format: 'Y-m-d H:i'
});
```