# How do I format datetimepicker visible value

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, return-value, datetimepicker

I want the selected date to be returned in a more readable format for the user. I already tried solutions suggested online

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
  });

  $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
  });
});
```

The selected date currently is shown to the user as:

```
0202/0707/19191919
```

Comment: format: 'd/m/Y'

Comment: Don't go crazy, use 
https://momentjs.com

Comment: @Anatsu how is Moment going to help you set the format of an unrelated datetime UI control?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#Inline

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37469675/6127393

Comment: @ArleighHix ah, I see the plugin uses PHP syntax for date formatting.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in response to your comment

Comment: @alex use  format:'d/m/Y'

Comment: @amit cant believe it was that easy! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 2):

This was answered simply by changing to `format: 'd/m/Y'`. Thanks to Amit

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the format like this, because datetimepicker takes format string as momentjs standards.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });

  $('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
});
```